# Radius of curvature of a surface - Is it related to the biggest circle tangent to a point $p$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785198/tamal-k-deys-curve-and-surface-reconstruction-lemma-3-3-normal-variation). I thought I was a good exercise to study how big the circle tangent to a surface whose radius is the radius of curvature at that point.

What confuses me here however is that we different notions of curvatures, such as mean curvature, principal curvatures (which are actually a pair), normal curvature etc.

So I'm not even sure how to formulate what I want to prove.

Essentially what I'm asking is whether or not there's a relationship between the different notions of curvature and the biggest circle tangent to a surface at a given point and if yes what would be the statement that I would need prove of the form

> Let $S$ a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $K(p)$ be the curvature at $p$ (**Question** :which notion of curvature however?) then the circle tangent at $p$ with curvature $K(p)$ is the biggest circle tangent at $p$.

By biggest circle  (or maybe sphere in this case) I mean that if you take a bigger one then it would actually intersect the surface.

My main reference is Do Carmo's differential geometry of curves and surfaces for terminology and notation.

Answer (score 1):

Note:
On a surface in 3d space the radius of curvature at a given point takes on different values depending on the plane normal to the surface on which the circle lies.
The radius varies between a minimum and a maximum value, that is:
in general the *osculating* ball is actually an ellipsoid or a hyperboloid, because the center of curvature can move on the different side of the tangent plane .

Comment: I guess what you're saying is what "principle curvature" actually encode.

Comment: to my knowledge "principal curvature" indicate both the minimum and maximum, i.e. the curvature along the main axes of the osculating quadric.

Comment: Aren't ellipsoid and hyperboloid quadrics as well?